# why are my emails empty from this python code?

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

im trying to make a program whch sends mail after taking voice input using outlook as gmail is not supporting "less secure apps" anymore but the problem is all the mails which are being sent are empty and without a subject

```
#this is my function


def Email(to,subject,content):
    message = EmailMessage()
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["From"] = "email@outlook.com"
    message["To"] = to
    message.set_content(content)
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("email@outlook.com","password")
    server.sendmail("email@outlook.com",to,content)
    server.close()

#AND THIS IS MY FUNCTION CALL
if "send a mail" in query:
    try:
        print("Who do u want to send the mail to?")
        speak("Who do u want to send the mail to?")
        print(mail_dict)
        to = (mail_dict[command()])
        print("what do should I Send?")
        speak("What should I send?")
        subject = "hello from python"
        content = command()
        Email(to,subject,content)
        print("The email was sent.")
        speak("The email was sent.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("sorry! the mail was not sent")
```

Comment: print the ```content``` var. Anything in it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes the content variable takes whatever voice input I give it                                   
 'what do should I Send?
Listening...
input = how are you

user said:how are you
The email was sent.'